# Is there somewhere a Yaml or SQL insert list of all countries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, yaml, iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get a list of all countries/cities to populate a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788950/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-countries-cities-to-populate-a-listbox)

I am looking for a script to create all the countries. Somebody knows an free ISO list i can easily use in Ruby?

I can find lists on google but I am not lucky with a yaml, csv or SQL inserts.

I am also very interested in all the cities in Spain.

EDIT: Countries + Country code

Edit2: Just interested in all cities of Spain.

Comment: Is this any good: http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt ?

Comment: Nice one Matt! And the list is very current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:  http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Comment: Thanks for this! That list is perfect if i want to have the cities for the country. Now only the list of Countries.

Answer (score 2):

I've just been searching for something similar myself and came across the World Countries API, which has a link there to a JSON file; http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json.

You can also pull out info on a per country basis. Here's Spain; http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/ES.json

One really nice thing about this API is that it provides plenty more info than the basic country name/code. Here's an example of the output;

```
"ES": {
   "Name": "Spain",
   "Capital": {
      "DLST": 1,
      "TD": 1,
      "Flg": 2,
      "Name": "Madrid",
      "GeoPt": [
         40.24,
         -3.41
      ]
   },
   "GeoRectangle": {
      "West": -18.169641,
      "East": 4.3153896,
      "North": 43.791725,
      "South": 27.638817
   },
   "SeqID": 66,
   "GeoPt": [
      40,
      -4
   ],
   "TelPref": "34",
   "CountryCodes": {
      "tld": "es",
      "iso3": "ESP",
      "iso2": "ES",
      "fips": "SP",
      "isoN": 724
   },
   "CountryInfo": "http://www.geognos.com/geo/en/cc/es.html"
},
```

I didn't look but perhaps they have cities per country info.

It's also a shame they don't include the native language(s) that are spoken but hey, it's still a good resource.

*P.S. I know you asked for YAML, but you can use JSON in Ruby and there are also YAML/JSON converters about.*

Answer (score 1):

If CSV is okay, this is based on ISO 3166: http://www.guavastudios.com/downloads/countries/countries.csv

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks very nice but it is without country code. Sorry didnt mention that in the question. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

A great place to find this kind of data is http://thedatahub.org/ service. It supports a RESTful API.