# How to populate a dropdownlist with all countries?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get a list of all countries/cities to populate a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788950/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-countries-cities-to-populate-a-listbox)

I'm trying to fill my dropdownlist with all world countries from windows, is there any way to make my dropdownlist get **all** countries from windows?

Or do anybody have a XML with all the list so I can use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update 8/9/2016:*

[List of Countries](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kalinchernev/486393efcca01623b18d/raw/daa24c9fea66afb7d68f8d69f0c4b8eeb9406e83/countries)

---

<strike>Just did a quick search and found this site:</strike>

http://madskristensen.net.web7.reliabledomainspace.com/post/XML-country-list.aspx.

Here's the direct link to the file:

http://cid-247fb0008340dbcd.office.live.com/self.aspx/workstion/countries.xml

Update: Code to populate your drop down list with the list of countries:

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load("path to url\file")

Dim countries = From c in doc.Descendants("country")
                Select c.Value

For Each country In countries
    DropDownList.Add(country)
Next

DropDownList.DataBind()
```

Comment: You did not check, there is download link of Countries.xml file.

Comment: this on is good but i have to modify it all , because it is only giving the code or iso only but name is not there

Comment: hahahahah i modified it all and now it's working please add this link to your answer

http://cid-247fb0008340dbcd.office.live.com/self.aspx/workstion/countries.xml

Comment: URL to http://madskristensen.net.web7.reliabledomainspace.com no longer works.

Comment: @Rich - I added a new link.