# Get list of countries and /or list of cities via web service

Tags: service, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get a list of all countries/cities to populate a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788950/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-countries-cities-to-populate-a-listbox)

Is there any web service which provides a list of all (almost all) countries and/or a list of all (almost all) cities of the world?

Answer (score 5):

you could use the GeoName API.

http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html#citiesJSON

for more info

http://www.geonames.org/

Comment: Nice, but the script url is http:// - not secure, so it is blocked by their own demo.