# Android string-array with all countries in different languages

Tags: android, xml, arrays

I've been googling for this resource, but couldn't find anything in the fly, does anyone know where I can find a list of all countries in the world in this format and in different languages?

is there a place where I can find this information?

```
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Australia</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
        <item>Cameroon</item>
        <item>Denmark</item>
        <item>(...)</item>  

    </string-array>
```

Thank you

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898694/list-of-all-countries-in-any-language) post might help you

Comment: Note that there's no consensus on what is and isn't a country, so getting a complete list is impossible.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I ended up finding a nice list in English. I'll leave it here, for future use in the case someone needs it. I'll try to find in different languages, or try to construct it...

If posting it here is not standard procedure, I'll save it somewhere and post a link.

Thank you

```
 <string-array name="countries_array">
    <item>Afghanistan</item>
    <item>Albania</item>
    <item>Algeria</item>
    <item>American Samoa</item>
    <item>Andorra</item>
    <item>Angola</item>
    <item>Anguilla</item>
    <item>Antarctica</item>
    <item>Antigua and Barbuda</item>
    <item>Argentina</item>
    <item>Armenia</item>
    <item>Aruba</item>
    <item>Australia</item>
    <item>Austria</item>
    <item>Azerbaijan</item>
    <item>Bahrain</item>
    <item>Bangladesh</item>
    <item>Barbados</item>
    <item>Belarus</item>
    <item>Belgium</item>
    <item>Belize</item>
    <item>Benin</item>
    <item>Bermuda</item>
    <item>Bhutan</item>
    <item>Bolivia</item>
    <item>Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
    <item>Botswana</item>
    <item>Bouvet Island</item>
    <item>Brazil</item>
    <item>British Indian Ocean Territory</item>
    <item>British Virgin Islands</item>
    <item>Brunei</item>
    <item>Bulgaria</item>
    <item>Burkina Faso</item>
    <item>Burundi</item>
    <item>Cambodia</item>
    <item>Cameroon</item>
    <item>Canada</item>
    <item>Cape Verde</item>
    <item>Cayman Islands</item>
    <item>Central African Republic</item>
    <item>Chad</item>
    <item>Chile</item>
    <item>China</item>
    <item>Christmas Island</item>
    <item>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</item>
    <item>Colombia</item>
    <item>Comoros</item>
    <item>Congo</item>
    <item>Cook Islands</item>
    <item>Costa Rica</item>
    <item>Cote d\'Ivoire</item>
    <item>Croatia</item>
    <item>Cuba</item>
    <item>Cyprus</item>
    <item>Czech Republic</item>
    <item>Democratic Republic of the Congo</item>
    <item>Denmark</item>
    <item>Djibouti</item>
    <item>Dominica</item>
    <item>Dominican Republic</item>
    <item>East Timor</item>
    <item>Ecuador</item>
    <item>Egypt</item>
    <item>El Salvador</item>
    <item>Equatorial Guinea</item>
    <item>Eritrea</item>
    <item>Estonia</item>
    <item>Ethiopia</item>
    <item>Faeroe Islands</item>
    <item>Falkland Islands</item>
    <item>Fiji</item>
    <item>Finland</item>
    <item>Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>French Guiana</item>
    <item>French Polynesia</item>
    <item>French Southern Territories</item>
    <item>Gabon</item>
    <item>Georgia</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Ghana</item>
    <item>Gibraltar</item>
    <item>Greece</item>
    <item>Greenland</item>
    <item>Grenada</item>
    <item>Guadeloupe</item>
    <item>Guam</item>
    <item>Guatemala</item>
    <item>Guinea</item>
    <item>Guinea-Bissau</item>
    <item>Guyana</item>
    <item>Haiti</item>
    <item>Heard Island and McDonald Islands</item>
    <item>Honduras</item>
    <item>Hong Kong</item>
    <item>Hungary</item>
    <item>Iceland</item>
    <item>India</item>
    <item>Indonesia</item>
    <item>Iran</item>
    <item>Iraq</item>
    <item>Ireland</item>
    <item>Israel</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>Jamaica</item>
    <item>Japan</item>
    <item>Jordan</item>
    <item>Kazakhstan</item>
    <item>Kenya</item>
    <item>Kiribati</item>
    <item>Kuwait</item>
    <item>Kyrgyzstan</item>
    <item>Laos</item>
    <item>Latvia</item>
    <item>Lebanon</item>
    <item>Lesotho</item>
    <item>Liberia</item>
    <item>Libya</item>
    <item>Liechtenstein</item>
    <item>Lithuania</item>
    <item>Luxembourg</item>
    <item>Macau</item>
    <item>Madagascar</item>
    <item>Malawi</item>
    <item>Malaysia</item>
    <item>Maldives</item>
    <item>Mali</item>
    <item>Malta</item>
    <item>Marshall Islands</item>
    <item>Martinique</item>
    <item>Mauritania</item>
    <item>Mauritius</item>
    <item>Mayotte</item>
    <item>Mexico</item>
    <item>Micronesia</item>
    <item>Moldova</item>
    <item>Monaco</item>
    <item>Mongolia</item>
    <item>Montenegro</item>
    <item>Montserrat</item>
    <item>Morocco</item>
    <item>Mozambique</item>
    <item>Myanmar</item>
    <item>Namibia</item>
    <item>Nauru</item>
    <item>Nepal</item>
    <item>Netherlands</item>
    <item>Netherlands Antilles</item>
    <item>New Caledonia</item>
    <item>New Zealand</item>
    <item>Nicaragua</item>
    <item>Niger</item>
    <item>Nigeria</item>
    <item>Niue</item>
    <item>Norfolk Island</item>
    <item>North Korea</item>
    <item>Northern Marianas</item>
    <item>Norway</item>
    <item>Oman</item>
    <item>Pakistan</item>
    <item>Palau</item>
    <item>Panama</item>
    <item>Papua New Guinea</item>
    <item>Paraguay</item>
    <item>Peru</item>
    <item>Philippines</item>
    <item>Pitcairn Islands</item>
    <item>Poland</item>
    <item>Portugal</item>
    <item>Puerto Rico</item>
    <item>Qatar</item>
    <item>Reunion</item>
    <item>Romania</item>
    <item>Russia</item>
    <item>Rwanda</item>
    <item>Sqo Tome and Principe</item>
    <item>Saint Helena</item>
    <item>Saint Kitts and Nevis</item>
    <item>Saint Lucia</item>
    <item>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</item>
    <item>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</item>
    <item>Samoa</item>
    <item>San Marino</item>
    <item>Saudi Arabia</item>
    <item>Senegal</item>
    <item>Serbia</item>
    <item>Seychelles</item>
    <item>Sierra Leone</item>
    <item>Singapore</item>
    <item>Slovakia</item>
    <item>Slovenia</item>
    <item>Solomon Islands</item>
    <item>Somalia</item>
    <item>South Africa</item>
    <item>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</item>
    <item>South Korea</item>
    <item>South Sudan</item>
    <item>Spain</item>
    <item>Sri Lanka</item>
    <item>Sudan</item>
    <item>Suriname</item>
    <item>Svalbard and Jan Mayen</item>
    <item>Swaziland</item>
    <item>Sweden</item>
    <item>Switzerland</item>
    <item>Syria</item>
    <item>Taiwan</item>
    <item>Tajikistan</item>
    <item>Tanzania</item>
    <item>Thailand</item>
    <item>The Bahamas</item>
    <item>The Gambia</item>
    <item>Togo</item>
    <item>Tokelau</item>
    <item>Tonga</item>
    <item>Trinidad and Tobago</item>
    <item>Tunisia</item>
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Turkmenistan</item>
    <item>Turks and Caicos Islands</item>
    <item>Tuvalu</item>
    <item>Virgin Islands</item>
    <item>Uganda</item>
    <item>Ukraine</item>
    <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>United States</item>
    <item>United States Minor Outlying Islands</item>
    <item>Uruguay</item>
    <item>Uzbekistan</item>
    <item>Vanuatu</item>
    <item>Vatican City</item>
    <item>Venezuela</item>
    <item>Vietnam</item>
    <item>Wallis and Futuna</item>
    <item>Western Sahara</item>
    <item>Yemen</item>
    <item>Yugoslavia</item>
    <item>Zambia</item>
    <item>Zimbabwe</item>
 </string-array>
```

Comment: This list is outdated, it has Yugoslavia which is long gone.

Comment: what happens if someone is born in ex-Yugoslavia and they're doing paperwork, how would they answer the question "What country are you born in?"

Comment: this has some country codes are wrong mapped checked below gist

https://gist.github.com/AJayBhimani74/c518431a2202ba8dac2bf5020c2fef56

Answer (score 18):

Here is an updated list of all the countries in the world.

```
<string-array name="countries_array">
    <item>Afghanistan</item>
    <item>Albania</item>
    <item>Algeria</item>
    <item>American Samoa</item>
    <item>Andorra</item>
    <item>Angola</item>
    <item>Anguilla</item>
    <item>Antarctica</item>
    <item>Antigua and Barbuda</item>
    <item>Argentina</item>
    <item>Armenia</item>
    <item>Aruba</item>
    <item>Australia</item>
    <item>Austria</item>
    <item>Azerbaijan</item>
    <item>Bahamas</item>
    <item>Bahrain</item>
    <item>Bangladesh</item>
    <item>Barbados</item>
    <item>Belarus</item>
    <item>Belgium</item>
    <item>Belize</item>
    <item>Benin</item>
    <item>Bermuda</item>
    <item>Bhutan</item>
    <item>Bolivia</item>
    <item>Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
    <item>Botswana</item>
    <item>Brazil</item>
    <item>British Indian Ocean Territory</item>
    <item>British Virgin Islands</item>
    <item>Brunei</item>
    <item>Bulgaria</item>
    <item>Burkina Faso</item>
    <item>Burundi</item>
    <item>Cambodia</item>
    <item>Cameroon</item>
    <item>Canada</item>
    <item>Cape Verde</item>
    <item>Cayman Islands</item>
    <item>Central African Republic</item>
    <item>Chad</item>
    <item>Chile</item>
    <item>China</item>
    <item>Christmas Island</item>
    <item>Cocos Islands</item>
    <item>Colombia</item>
    <item>Comoros</item>
    <item>Cook Islands</item>
    <item>Costa Rica</item>
    <item>Croatia</item>
    <item>Cuba</item>
    <item>Cyprus</item>
    <item>Czech Republic</item>
    <item>Democratic Republic of the Congo</item>
    <item>Denmark</item>
    <item>Djibouti</item>
    <item>Dominica</item>
    <item>Dominican Republic</item>
    <item>East Timor</item>
    <item>Ecuador</item>
    <item>Egypt</item>
    <item>El Salvador</item>
    <item>Equatorial Guinea</item>
    <item>Eritrea</item>
    <item>Estonia</item>
    <item>Ethiopia</item>
    <item>Falkland Islands</item>
    <item>Faroe Islands</item>
    <item>Fiji</item>
    <item>Finland</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>French Polynesia</item>
    <item>Gabon</item>
    <item>Gambia</item>
    <item>Georgia</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Ghana</item>
    <item>Gibraltar</item>
    <item>Greece</item>
    <item>Greenland</item>
    <item>Grenada</item>
    <item>Guam</item>
    <item>Guatemala</item>
    <item>Guinea</item>
    <item>Guinea-Bissau</item>
    <item>Guyana</item>
    <item>Haiti</item>
    <item>Honduras</item>
    <item>Hong Kong</item>
    <item>Hungary</item>
    <item>Iceland</item>
    <item>India</item>
    <item>Indonesia</item>
    <item>Iran</item>
    <item>Iraq</item>
    <item>Ireland</item>
    <item>Isle of Man</item>
    <item>Israel</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>Ivory Coast</item>
    <item>Jamaica</item>
    <item>Japan</item>
    <item>Jersey</item>
    <item>Jordan</item>
    <item>Kazakhstan</item>
    <item>Kenya</item>
    <item>Kiribati</item>
    <item>Kuwait</item>
    <item>Kyrgyzstan</item>
    <item>Laos</item>
    <item>Latvia</item>
    <item>Lebanon</item>
    <item>Lesotho</item>
    <item>Liberia</item>
    <item>Libya</item>
    <item>Liechtenstein</item>
    <item>Lithuania</item>
    <item>Luxembourg</item>
    <item>Macao</item>
    <item>Macedonia</item>
    <item>Madagascar</item>
    <item>Malawi</item>
    <item>Malaysia</item>
    <item>Maldives</item>
    <item>Mali</item>
    <item>Malta</item>
    <item>Marshall Islands</item>
    <item>Mauritania</item>
    <item>Mauritius</item>
    <item>Mayotte</item>
    <item>Mexico</item>
    <item>Micronesia</item>
    <item>Moldova</item>
    <item>Monaco</item>
    <item>Mongolia</item>
    <item>Montenegro</item>
    <item>Montserrat</item>
    <item>Morocco</item>
    <item>Mozambique</item>
    <item>Myanmar</item>
    <item>Namibia</item>
    <item>Nauru</item>
    <item>Nepal</item>
    <item>Netherlands</item>
    <item>Netherlands Antilles</item>
    <item>New Caledonia</item>
    <item>New Zealand</item>
    <item>Nicaragua</item>
    <item>Niger</item>
    <item>Nigeria</item>
    <item>Niue</item>
    <item>North Korea</item>
    <item>Northern Mariana Islands</item>
    <item>Norway</item>
    <item>Oman</item>
    <item>Pakistan</item>
    <item>Palau</item>
    <item>Panama</item>
    <item>Papua New Guinea</item>
    <item>Paraguay</item>
    <item>Peru</item>
    <item>Philippines</item>
    <item>Pitcairn</item>
    <item>Poland</item>
    <item>Portugal</item>
    <item>Puerto Rico</item>
    <item>Qatar</item>
    <item>Republic of the Congo</item>
    <item>Romania</item>
    <item>Russia</item>
    <item>Rwanda</item>
    <item>Saint Barthelemy</item>
    <item>Saint Helena</item>
    <item>Saint Kitts and Nevis</item>
    <item>Saint Lucia</item>
    <item>Saint Martin</item>
    <item>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</item>
    <item>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</item>
    <item>Samoa</item>
    <item>San Marino</item>
    <item>Sao Tome and Principe</item>
    <item>Saudi Arabia</item>
    <item>Senegal</item>
    <item>Serbia</item>
    <item>Seychelles</item>
    <item>Sierra Leone</item>
    <item>Singapore</item>
    <item>Slovakia</item>
    <item>Slovenia</item>
    <item>Solomon Islands</item>
    <item>Somalia</item>
    <item>South Africa</item>
    <item>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</item>
    <item>South Korea</item>
    <item>Spain</item>
    <item>Sri Lanka</item>
    <item>Sudan</item>
    <item>Suriname</item>
    <item>Svalbard and Jan Mayen</item>
    <item>Swaziland</item>
    <item>Sweden</item>
    <item>Switzerland</item>
    <item>Syria</item>
    <item>Taiwan</item>
    <item>Tajikistan</item>
    <item>Tanzania</item>
    <item>Thailand</item>
    <item>Togo</item>
    <item>Tokelau</item>
    <item>Tonga</item>
    <item>Trinidad and Tobago</item>
    <item>Tunisia</item>
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Turkmenistan</item>
    <item>Turks and Caicos Islands</item>
    <item>Tuvalu</item>
    <item>U.S. Virgin Islands</item>
    <item>Uganda</item>
    <item>Ukraine</item>
    <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>United States</item>
    <item>Uruguay</item>
    <item>Uzbekistan</item>
    <item>Vanuatu</item>
    <item>Vatican</item>
    <item>Venezuela</item>
    <item>Vietnam</item>
    <item>Wallis and Futuna</item>
    <item>Western Sahara</item>
    <item>Yemen</item>
    <item>Zambia</item>
    <item>Zimbabwe</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 7):

In case that String array format needed.

```
 String[] countries = new String[]{"Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla",
            "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas",
            "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegowina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam",
            "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands",
            "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China, People's republic of", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia",
            "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire",
            "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
            "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia",
            "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana",
            "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
            "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti",
            "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India",
            "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan",
            "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kosovo", "Kuwait",
            "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya",
            "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar",
            "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius",
            "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat",
            "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles",
            "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands",
            "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Palestine", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn",
            "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda",
            "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino",
            "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore",
            "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa",
            "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon",
            "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic",
            "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Tibet", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga",
            "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine",
            "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay",
            "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)",
            "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below links which may help:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_spoken_languages

Comment: Thank you, those are actually great articles! They might come in handy!

Answer (score 1):

In case you need the pair country code - name. This might be helpful:
[source](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-country-names/)

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CountryList {
    public static List<Country> get() {
        // A collection to store our country object
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

        // Get ISO countries, create Country object and
        // store in the collection.
        String[] isoCountries = Locale.getISOCountries();
        for (String country : isoCountries) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("en", country);
            String iso = locale.getISO3Country();
            String code = locale.getCountry();
            String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();

            if (!"".equals(iso) && !"".equals(code) && !"".equals(name)) {
                countries.add(new Country(iso, code, name));
            }
        }

        // Sort the country by their name and then display the content
        // of countries collection object.
        Collections.sort(countries, new CountryComparator());
        return countries;
    }

    /**
     * Country pojo class.
     */
    public static class Country {
        private String iso;
        private String code;
        private String name;

        Country(String iso, String code, String name) {
            this.iso = iso;
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return iso + " - " + code + " - " + name.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    /**
     * CountryComparator class.
     */
    private static class CountryComparator implements Comparator<Country> {
        private Comparator<Object> comparator;

        CountryComparator() {
            comparator = Collator.getInstance();
        }

        public int compare(Country c1, Country c2) {
            return comparator.compare(c1.name, c2.name);
        }
    }
}
```