# Array.xml list for both countries and nationalities

Tags: android

Been looking for a complete list of a ready made `<string-array>` for both countries and nationalities, for Android.

Found the countries list courtesy of this link (thanks!) https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788683/6842292

Needing to find one for nationalities too (e.g. England = English, Germany = German etc.)

Comment: you can use Java's Locale i believe

Comment: I didn't think it offered nationalities though, just regions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up rolling my own list for nationalities, surrounding all in `<item></item>` tags, so thought I'd leave both here side by side for any future users:

```
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Afghanistan</item>
        <item>Albania</item>
        <item>Algeria</item>
        <item>American Samoa</item>
        <item>Andorra</item>
        <item>Angola</item>
        <item>Anguilla</item>
        <item>Antarctica</item>
        <item>Antigua and Barbuda</item>
        <item>Argentina</item>
        <item>Armenia</item>
        <item>Aruba</item>
        <item>Australia</item>
        <item>Austria</item>
        <item>Azerbaijan</item>
        <item>Bahamas</item>
        <item>Bahrain</item>
        <item>Bangladesh</item>
        <item>Barbados</item>
        <item>Belarus</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
        <item>Belize</item>
        <item>Benin</item>
        <item>Bermuda</item>
        <item>Bhutan</item>
        <item>Bolivia</item>
        <item>Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
        <item>Botswana</item>
        <item>Brazil</item>
        <item>British Indian Ocean Territory</item>
        <item>British Virgin Islands</item>
        <item>Brunei</item>
        <item>Bulgaria</item>
        <item>Burkina Faso</item>
        <item>Burundi</item>
        <item>Cambodia</item>
        <item>Cameroon</item>
        <item>Canada</item>
        <item>Cape Verde</item>
        <item>Cayman Islands</item>
        <item>Central African Republic</item>
        <item>Chad</item>
        <item>Chile</item>
        <item>China</item>
        <item>Christmas Island</item>
        <item>Cocos Islands</item>
        <item>Colombia</item>
        <item>Comoros</item>
        <item>Cook Islands</item>
        <item>Costa Rica</item>
        <item>Croatia</item>
        <item>Cuba</item>
        <item>Cyprus</item>
        <item>Czech Republic</item>
        <item>Democratic Republic of the Congo</item>
        <item>Denmark</item>
        <item>Djibouti</item>
        <item>Dominica</item>
        <item>Dominican Republic</item>
        <item>East Timor</item>
        <item>Ecuador</item>
        <item>Egypt</item>
        <item>El Salvador</item>
        <item>Equatorial Guinea</item>
        <item>Eritrea</item>
        <item>Estonia</item>
        <item>Ethiopia</item>
        <item>Falkland Islands</item>
        <item>Faroe Islands</item>
        <item>Fiji</item>
        <item>Finland</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>French Polynesia</item>
        <item>Gabon</item>
        <item>Gambia</item>
        <item>Georgia</item>
        <item>Germany</item>
        <item>Ghana</item>
        <item>Gibraltar</item>
        <item>Greece</item>
        <item>Greenland</item>
        <item>Grenada</item>
        <item>Guam</item>
        <item>Guatemala</item>
        <item>Guinea</item>
        <item>Guinea-Bissau</item>
        <item>Guyana</item>
        <item>Haiti</item>
        <item>Honduras</item>
        <item>Hong Kong</item>
        <item>Hungary</item>
        <item>Iceland</item>
        <item>India</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>Iran</item>
        <item>Iraq</item>
        <item>Ireland</item>
        <item>Isle of Man</item>
        <item>Israel</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Ivory Coast</item>
        <item>Jamaica</item>
        <item>Japan</item>
        <item>Jersey</item>
        <item>Jordan</item>
        <item>Kazakhstan</item>
        <item>Kenya</item>
        <item>Kiribati</item>
        <item>Kuwait</item>
        <item>Kyrgyzstan</item>
        <item>Laos</item>
        <item>Latvia</item>
        <item>Lebanon</item>
        <item>Lesotho</item>
        <item>Liberia</item>
        <item>Libya</item>
        <item>Liechtenstein</item>
        <item>Lithuania</item>
        <item>Luxembourg</item>
        <item>Macao</item>
        <item>Macedonia</item>
        <item>Madagascar</item>
        <item>Malawi</item>
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>Maldives</item>
        <item>Mali</item>
        <item>Malta</item>
        <item>Marshall Islands</item>
        <item>Mauritania</item>
        <item>Mauritius</item>
        <item>Mayotte</item>
        <item>Mexico</item>
        <item>Micronesia</item>
        <item>Moldova</item>
        <item>Monaco</item>
        <item>Mongolia</item>
        <item>Montenegro</item>
        <item>Montserrat</item>
        <item>Morocco</item>
        <item>Mozambique</item>
        <item>Myanmar</item>
        <item>Namibia</item>
        <item>Nauru</item>
        <item>Nepal</item>
        <item>Netherlands</item>
        <item>Netherlands Antilles</item>
        <item>New Caledonia</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>Nicaragua</item>
        <item>Niger</item>
        <item>Nigeria</item>
        <item>Niue</item>
        <item>North Korea</item>
        <item>Northern Mariana Islands</item>
        <item>Norway</item>
        <item>Oman</item>
        <item>Pakistan</item>
        <item>Palau</item>
        <item>Panama</item>
        <item>Papua New Guinea</item>
        <item>Paraguay</item>
        <item>Peru</item>
        <item>Philippines</item>
        <item>Pitcairn</item>
        <item>Poland</item>
        <item>Portugal</item>
        <item>Puerto Rico</item>
        <item>Qatar</item>
        <item>Republic of the Congo</item>
        <item>Romania</item>
        <item>Russia</item>
        <item>Rwanda</item>
        <item>Saint Barthelemy</item>
        <item>Saint Helena</item>
        <item>Saint Kitts and Nevis</item>
        <item>Saint Lucia</item>
        <item>Saint Martin</item>
        <item>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</item>
        <item>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</item>
        <item>Samoa</item>
        <item>San Marino</item>
        <item>Sao Tome and Principe</item>
        <item>Saudi Arabia</item>
        <item>Senegal</item>
        <item>Serbia</item>
        <item>Seychelles</item>
        <item>Sierra Leone</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>Slovakia</item>
        <item>Slovenia</item>
        <item>Solomon Islands</item>
        <item>Somalia</item>
        <item>South Africa</item>
        <item>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</item>
        <item>South Korea</item>
        <item>Spain</item>
        <item>Sri Lanka</item>
        <item>Sudan</item>
        <item>Suriname</item>
        <item>Svalbard and Jan Mayen</item>
        <item>Swaziland</item>
        <item>Sweden</item>
        <item>Switzerland</item>
        <item>Syria</item>
        <item>Taiwan</item>
        <item>Tajikistan</item>
        <item>Tanzania</item>
        <item>Thailand</item>
        <item>Togo</item>
        <item>Tokelau</item>
        <item>Tonga</item>
        <item>Trinidad and Tobago</item>
        <item>Tunisia</item>
        <item>Turkey</item>
        <item>Turkmenistan</item>
        <item>Turks and Caicos Islands</item>
        <item>Tuvalu</item>
        <item>U.S. Virgin Islands</item>
        <item>Uganda</item>
        <item>Ukraine</item>
        <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
        <item>United Kingdom</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Uruguay</item>
        <item>Uzbekistan</item>
        <item>Vanuatu</item>
        <item>Vatican</item>
        <item>Venezuela</item>
        <item>Vietnam</item>
        <item>Wallis and Futuna</item>
        <item>Western Sahara</item>
        <item>Yemen</item>
        <item>Zambia</item>
        <item>Zimbabwe</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="nationalities_array">
        <item>Afghan</item>
        <item>Albanian</item>
        <item>Algerian</item>
        <item>American</item>
        <item>Andorran</item>
        <item>Angolan</item>
        <item>Anguillan</item>
        <item>Citizen of Antigua and Barbuda</item>
        <item>Argentine</item>
        <item>Armenian</item>
        <item>Australian</item>
        <item>Austrian</item>
        <item>Azerbaijani</item>
        <item>Bahamian</item>
        <item>Bahraini</item>
        <item>Bangladeshi</item>
        <item>Barbadian</item>
        <item>Belarusian</item>
        <item>Belgian</item>
        <item>Belizean</item>
        <item>Beninese</item>
        <item>Bermudian</item>
        <item>Bhutanese</item>
        <item>Bolivian</item>
        <item>Citizen of Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
        <item>Botswanan</item>
        <item>Brazilian</item>
        <item>British</item>
        <item>British Virgin Islander</item>
        <item>Bruneian</item>
        <item>Bulgarian</item>
        <item>Burkinan</item>
        <item>Burmese</item>
        <item>Burundian</item>
        <item>Cambodian</item>
        <item>Cameroonian</item>
        <item>Canadian</item>
        <item>Cape Verdean</item>
        <item>Cayman Islander</item>
        <item>Central African</item>
        <item>Chadian</item>
        <item>Chilean</item>
        <item>Chinese</item>
        <item>Colombian</item>
        <item>Comoran</item>
        <item>Congolese (Congo)</item>
        <item>Congolese (DRC)</item>
        <item>Cook Islander</item>
        <item>Costa Rican</item>
        <item>Croatian</item>
        <item>Cuban</item>
        <item>Cymraes</item>
        <item>Cymro</item>
        <item>Cypriot</item>
        <item>Czech</item>
        <item>Danish</item>
        <item>Djiboutian</item>
        <item>Dominican</item>
        <item>Citizen of the Dominican Republic</item>
        <item>Dutch</item>
        <item>East Timorese</item>
        <item>Ecuadorean</item>
        <item>Egyptian</item>
        <item>Emirati</item>
        <item>English</item>
        <item>Equatorial</item>
        <item>Guinean</item>
        <item>Eritrean</item>
        <item>Estonian</item>
        <item>Ethiopian</item>
        <item>Faroese</item>
        <item>Fijian</item>
        <item>Filipino</item>
        <item>Finnish</item>
        <item>French</item>
        <item>Gabonese</item>
        <item>Gambian</item>
        <item>Georgian</item>
        <item>German</item>
        <item>Ghanaian</item>
        <item>Gibraltarian</item>
        <item>Greek</item>
        <item>Greenlandic</item>
        <item>Grenadian</item>
        <item>Guamanian</item>
        <item>Guatemalan</item>
        <item>Citizen of Guinea-Bissau</item>
        <item>Guinean</item>
        <item>Guyanese</item>
        <item>Haitian</item>
        <item>Honduran</item>
        <item>Hong Konger</item>
        <item>Hungarian</item>
        <item>Icelandic</item>
        <item>Indian</item>
        <item>Indonesian</item>
        <item>Iranian</item>
        <item>Iraqi</item>
        <item>Irish</item>
        <item>Israeli</item>
        <item>Italian</item>
        <item>Ivorian</item>
        <item>Jamaican</item>
        <item>Japanese</item>
        <item>Jordanian</item>
        <item>Kazakh</item>
        <item>Kenyan</item>
        <item>Kittitian</item>
        <item>Citizen of Kiribati</item>
        <item>Kosovan</item>
        <item>Kuwaiti</item>
        <item>Kyrgyz</item>
        <item>Lao</item>
        <item>Latvian</item>
        <item>Lebanese</item>
        <item>Liberian</item>
        <item>Libyan</item>
        <item>Liechtenstein citizen</item>
        <item>Lithuanian</item>
        <item>Luxembourger</item>
        <item>Macanese</item>
        <item>Macedonian</item>
        <item>Malagasy</item>
        <item>Malawian</item>
        <item>Malaysian</item>
        <item>Maldivian</item>
        <item>Malian</item>
        <item>Maltese</item>
        <item>Marshallese</item>
        <item>Martiniquais</item>
        <item>Mauritanian</item>
        <item>Mauritian</item>
        <item>Mexican</item>
        <item>Micronesian</item>
        <item>Moldovan</item>
        <item>Monegasque</item>
        <item>Mongolian</item>
        <item>Montenegrin</item>
        <item>Montserratian</item>
        <item>Moroccan</item>
        <item>Mosotho</item>
        <item>Mozambican</item>
        <item>Namibian</item>
        <item>Nauruan</item>
        <item>Nepalese</item>
        <item>New Zealander</item>
        <item>Nicaraguan</item>
        <item>Nigerian</item>
        <item>Nigerien</item>
        <item>Niuean</item>
        <item>North Korean</item>
        <item>Northern Irish</item>
        <item>Norwegian</item>
        <item>Omani</item>
        <item>Pakistani</item>
        <item>Palauan</item>
        <item>Palestinian</item>
        <item>Panamanian</item>
        <item>Papua New Guinean</item>
        <item>Paraguayan</item>
        <item>Peruvian</item>
        <item>Pitcairn Islander</item>
        <item>Polish</item>
        <item>Portuguese</item>
        <item>Prydeinig</item>
        <item>Puerto Rican</item>
        <item>Qatari</item>
        <item>Romanian</item>
        <item>Russian</item>
        <item>Rwandan</item>
        <item>Salvadorean</item>
        <item>Sammarinese</item>
        <item>Samoan</item>
        <item>Sao Tomean</item>
        <item>Saudi Arabian</item>
        <item>Scottish</item>
        <item>Senegalese</item>
        <item>Serbian</item>
        <item>Citizen of Seychelles</item>
        <item>Sierra Leonean</item>
        <item>Singaporean</item>
        <item>Slovak</item>
        <item>Slovenian</item>
        <item>Solomon Islander</item>
        <item>Somali</item>
        <item>South African</item>
        <item>South Korean</item>
        <item>South</item>
        <item>Sudanese</item>
        <item>Spanish</item>
        <item>Sri Lankan</item>
        <item>St Helenian</item>
        <item>St Lucian</item>
        <item>Stateless</item>
        <item>Sudanese</item>
        <item>Surinamese</item>
        <item>Swazi</item>
        <item>Swedish</item>
        <item>Swiss</item>
        <item>Syrian</item>
        <item>Taiwanese</item>
        <item>Tajik</item>
        <item>Tanzanian</item>
        <item>Thai</item>
        <item>Togolese</item>
        <item>Tongan</item>
        <item>Trinidadian</item>
        <item>Tristanian</item>
        <item>Tunisian</item>
        <item>Turkish</item>
        <item>Turkmen</item>
        <item>Turks and Caicos Islander</item>
        <item>Tuvaluan</item>
        <item>Ugandan</item>
        <item>Ukrainian</item>
        <item>Uruguayan</item>
        <item>Uzbek</item>
        <item>Vatican citizen</item>
        <item>Citizen of Vanuatu</item>
        <item>Venezuelan</item>
        <item>Vietnamese</item>
        <item>Vincentian</item>
        <item>Wallisian</item>
        <item>Welsh</item>
        <item>Yemeni</item>
        <item>Zambian</item>
        <item>Zimbabwean</item>
    </string-array>
```

Again, credit to this answer for the countries list https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788683/6842292