# How small can a JavaScript number be without displaying in scientific notation?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, scientific-notation

I've made some code that rounds off a number to a given number of decimal places but will use more places when there is underflow to avoid rounding just to zero, which wouldn't be informative enough for the user.

But I've noticed that occasionally a small number is displayed in scientific notation. My target users are not expected to be comfortable with scientific notation and in any case such numbers are too small even after handling the underflow and should be treated as zero.

How can I know when a number is so small that it would display in scientific notation?

Is there a smallest number I can compare to and if so what is it?
Or is there a better way?

(I know I can convert the number to a string and check if it has an "e" but I'm the type who is curious to know of any math-only solution too.)

Comment: Why not just get the string form of the number and check for an embedded "e"?

Comment: @Pointy: Oh for my sake of curiosity I'd like to know how to do it mathematically. I meant to include that in the question. Let me edit it ...

Comment: Well the trick is that floating-point math is pretty complicated, while checking for an "e" is really easy :)

Comment: Yeah the trickier the stuff the more I want to know how to do it!

Comment: the result may depend on a browser and the best solution is to check `myNum.toString()` for `e`.

Comment: Did a quick test along the browsers on my Computer (current FF, Chrome, Edge), `1e-6` seems to be the smallest number that ain't printed in scientific notation when converting the value to a String. So everything that is `Math.abs(value) >= 1e-6` should be safe

Comment: @AlexKudryashev: Yes that was one thing I was wondering. A lot of EcmaScript is standardized now, but maybe this is a bit that isn't.

Comment: Also, it seems that **e** is [not necessarily universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436573/localized-exponential-notation) as it is subject to localization in Unicode's [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index). Doing math with numbers is just more elegant than doing it with strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few reasons the number is displayed in scientific notation:

- If the length of significant digits in the number is greater than 21.
- If the number of zeros before a nonzero number is greater than 6. (e.g. 0.00000001)

The conversion to scientific notation in numbers is specified in [Section 9.8.1 of ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1).

An implementation of this specification can be found in the [V8 engine here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c58460b25f69acb2250d1d34af022de8b6c76bd6/src/conversions.cc#L125).