# un expected behavior in v-text-field type number

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**I have v-text-field of type number with min and max props**
**When the value entered exceeds max it gives an un-understandable value**
**and the rules message disappears**
***this is my code***

```
<v-text-field
    v-model.number="salaryClientRate"
    outlined
    clearable
    min="1"
    type="number"
    color="grey darken-1"
    max="9999999999"
    :rules="[validationRules.salary]"
  >
    <template #message="{ message }">
      <template>
        {{ $t(message) }}
      </template>
    </template>
  </v-text-field>
```

[image that describe the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVQHi.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231666/2074736

Comment: you already have `type="number"` which will prevent non-numeric input.  you don't need to additionally cast the v-model value as a number which is causing your scientific notation issues.  change `v-model.number=` to just `v-model=`

Comment: @yoduh in this case the value of text field will be string not number

Comment: The user will not know the difference.  Within your methods you can cast it as a number if you need to perform some numerical operation on it.  This is just to avoid your issue with scientific notation if you find no other solution